# Angular 2 Observable Error Handling

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I did create my own Observable service that return current tracks of a player.

I'm subscribing to this service on my Angular component this way:

```
this.playerSubscription = this.player
      .player(playlist)
      .subscribe(
        playerInfo => this.playerInfo = playerInfo,
        error => this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { error: 'expired_token' }})
      );
```

As you can see, when I have an error, I redirect the user to the login page.

The problem is when I do login after a previous error, the subscription returns to me the **lastest error sequence and I gonna redirected again to the login page.**

On my service, I'm using the BehaviorSubject and doing `subject.next(message)` to valid sequences, and `subject.error(error)` to send an error sequence.

How can I forget about the last error after resubscribing
 to my observable?

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1:**

I did some new tests here and it only works when I create a new subject every time I subscribe, like bellow:

```
player(playlist: IPlaylist, fromBegin: boolean): Observable<IPlayerInfo> {

    this._player = new BehaviorSubject<IPlayerInfo>({ status: PlayerStatuses.LOADING });

    ... more code here ...

    return this._player.asObservable();
  }
```

Nevermind if it's a `Subject` or a `BehaviorSubject`.

Is this a good practice?

Comment: I would do redirect to login inside you player method logic right before subject.error call or use auth guard  for players route.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add a router inside a service. I don't think it's a service responsibility to redirect the user for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I forget about the last error after resubscribing to my observable?

Use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`.

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
```

`BehaviorSubject` is one of `Subject` variant which remember `current value`. So if you do not want to get the latest value every time you `subscribe`, use `Subject`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I keep being redirect after the login with the last error.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I just update my question. Did some tests and it only works when I create a new subject every time I subscribe. Any thoughts?